# How to fire up a rabbitmq consumer in shared hosting

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, shared-hosting

I'm on a shared hosting, and I need to use rabbitmq.

I have an account in [cloudamqp.com](https://www.cloudamqp.com/), and I can send messages through there when I send from my localhost environment. I start the consumer in my localhost from Windows Power Shell, and I've set up the settings so that the message goes through the cloudamqp, and it works.

The question is: how do I start the consumer on shared hosting -server? I cannot open up a command line and write a command like this: "`php app/console rabbitmq:rpc-server test_server`", like I do in my local host environment.

Comment: That won't be possible on a shared hosting since you don't have access to a command line.

Comment: There's no workaround? Sad.. Just sad.. I guess I'll change to amazon servers, since they support rabbitmq.